# How to set a index to button ID in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Here I'm trying to set index to my button id, for example if I have button id like unique , second button should have unique0, and third button should have unique1 like this. actually button in each loop so that i am same id with all buttons anyone pls let me know how to achieve it

note: i need button id's like unique0, unique1, unique2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <button id="unique" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  var index = $("#unique").index(this);
  $("#unique").append(index);
  )};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `this` supposed to be? The code isn't  in an event handler associated with a particular button.

Comment: Are you sure you need the buttons to have IDs? If they're dynamically created, you can access them using indexes, not by ID.

Comment: Yes Barmar I'm getting button dynamically in my code but  i want append that id to button

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to change all the IDs.

```
$(".btn").each(function(i) {
    this.id = 'unique' + i;
    this.innerText += i;
});
```